# SNMP walk on only one level

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, sharp-snmp

Is there a way to walk only one level of the tree with SNMP?

Example:
I want to know how many tables my tree has but I don't want to walk each entry. It would be nice to only walk the parent level and return all OIDs for the root node of the table.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use `snmpwalk` (which I don't think supports the one level walk mentioned in question), it may be easier to get such info from the MIB file (instead of interrogating the agent).

It may be convenient to use tool like e.g. netsnmp `snmptranslate`. E.g. to see what tables live in SNMPv2-MIB::system  i.e. `1.3.6.1.2.1.1`,  you could ...

```
snmptranslate  -M +.  -m +ALL -Tp -On SNMPv2-MIB::system 
+--system(1)
   |
   +-- -R-- String    sysDescr(1)
   |        Textual Convention: DisplayString
   |        Size: 0..255
   +-- -R-- ObjID     sysObjectID(2)
   +-- -R-- TimeTicks sysUpTime(3)
   |  |
   |  +--sysUpTimeInstance(0)
   |
   +-- -RW- String    sysContact(4)
   |        Textual Convention: DisplayString
   |        Size: 0..255
   +-- -RW- String    sysName(5)
   |        Textual Convention: DisplayString
   |        Size: 0..255
   +-- -RW- String    sysLocation(6)
   |        Textual Convention: DisplayString
   |        Size: 0..255
   +-- -R-- INTEGER   sysServices(7)
   |        Range: 0..127
   +-- -R-- TimeTicks sysORLastChange(8)
   |        Textual Convention: TimeStamp
   |
   +--sysORTable(9)
      |
      +--sysOREntry(1)
         |  Index: sysORIndex
         |
         +-- ---- INTEGER   sysORIndex(1)
         |        Range: 1..2147483647
         +-- -R-- ObjID     sysORID(2)
         +-- -R-- String    sysORDescr(3)
         |        Textual Convention: DisplayString
         |        Size: 0..255
         +-- -R-- TimeTicks sysORUpTime(4)
                  Textual Convention: TimeStamp
```